# error al imprimir una matriz en un jtable

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

hola buenas me preguntaba si podrian ayudarme en este problema, me imagino que para ustedes les resultara facil pasa que intento imprimir los datos de una matriz en un jtable pero como veran no se me muestran me ayudarian explicandome que lo produce y como puedo solucionarlo

[image: Problema en el jtable]

en estas opciones cambie el tipo a string en lugar de objeto nose si funcione
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo

aqui muestro el arreglo

```
  public static void MostrarArreglo(String[][] Arreglo, DefaultTableModel tabla) {
        //Llenamos el modelo con los números del arreglo
        
         for (int x = 0; x < Arreglo.length; x++) {
            
            for (int y = 0; y < Arreglo.length ; y++) {
                
               
               tabla.setValueAt(Arreglo[x][y], x, y);
                
                       
            }
        }
        
    }
```

y aqui es donde lo llamo y le meto los parametros

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1_clientes.getModel();
            
        llenadoCliente(jTextField_cedula1.toString(), jTextField_cedula2.toString(), jTextField_cedula3.toString(), jTextField_nombre1.toString(), jTextField_nombre2.toString(), jTextField_nombre3.toString(), jTextField_telefono1.toString(), jTextField_telefono2.toString(), jTextField_telefono3.toString());
        

        MostrarArreglo(vectorCliente, model);
```

les agradesco de antemano toda la ayuda muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambiar los datos de tipo Object a tipo String para luego pasar un objeto convertido a cadena, es lo mismo que pasar el objeto.

En otras palabras, lo produce ese comportamiento a la hora de mostrar los datos en la tabla, es que estas pasando por parámetro lo que devuelve el método `toString()` en vez del texto que tiene el JTextField.

Ese método lo que hace es convertir un Objeto Java a una cadena de texto.

Entonces si tienes un JTextField como este:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField("Hola mundo", 57);
field.setOpaque(true);
field.setEditable(false);
field.setCaretColor(Color.BLUE);
field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
field.setAlignmentX(1);

System.out.println(field.toString());
```

Devolverá lo siguiente:

```
javax.swing.JTextField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=1.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@1d119efb,flags=16777512,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=false,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=57,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=RIGHT]
```

Ahí puedes ver que el método devuelve las propiedades del objeto en una cadena de texto, incluyendo los cambios que hice como: columns=57, alignmentX=1, editable=false.

---

¿Como se soluciona? En vez de utilizar toStr... simplemente agrega en los parámetros el texto que contiene el JTextField y no el JTextField.

```
llenadoCliente(jTextField_cedula1.getText(), jTextField_cedula2.getText(), jTextField_cedula3.getText(), jTextField_nombre1.getText(), jTextField_nombre2.getText(), jTextField_nombre3.getText(), jTextField_telefono1.getText(), jTextField_telefono2.getText(), jTextField_telefono3.getText());
```

Comment: jejje muchas gracias, si el error no era muy complejo, muchas gracias @JFrame